# Front End changes "\r" to "\n" when saving notebooks

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, notebooks

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.1**

---

When saving notebooks, the Front End destroys `"\r"` appearing in code and converts it to `"\n"`.  Here are minimal steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Enter this in a notebook, then evaluate it:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{},
    "Empty",
    Initialization :> "\r\n"
   ]
   ```
2. Save the notebook.
3. Open the notebook in a text editor and look at its expression.  I see

   ```
   Initialization:>"\n\n"
   ```

   The `\r` has been changed to an `\n`.

I observe this on OS X with M9.0.1–M11.1.0.  Do other people see it?  Is it a bug?  Is there a simple workaround?

In my actual use case, I have `StringReplace[..., {"\r\n" -> "\n", "\r" -> "\n"}]` in `Initialization`.  This gets mangled and made non-functional by this problem.

---

Reported as CASE:3873908.

Comment: Same on Win10 V11.1.

Comment: Same with Mathematica 8.0.4 on Win7x64.

Answer (score 3):

One possible workaround is using

```
FromCharacterCode[{13}]
```

in place of

```
"\r"
```

Comment: Another one, also reducing the size of the palette: `With[{init = 
   Compress @ 
    Unevaluated @ (Print @ 
       Style["test\r", ShowStringCharacters -> True])},
 DynamicModule[{}, "Empty", Initialization :> (Uncompress@init)]
 ]`. Probably blocked context would be on point. Another closely related solution: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86707/5478