# How to save a context into an expression?

Tags: export, core-language, contexts

```
BeginPackage["foo`"];
    bar;
Begin["`Private`"];    
    bar[] := bar[ $Context, $ContextPath];    
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

So I'd like to have all information about `` foo` `` stored in an expression.

It may be useful in something like [How can I include functions from a package into a CDF file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86674/5478) where the package is spread over many files.

- `DumpSave` is not portable enough
- `Save` saves `$Context` and `$ContextPath` (everything what is not protected) together with all definitions so loading it will affect environment.

  I can load it within additional `Begin/EndPackage` but I don't like it.
- I don't know how to use `` Language` `` functions to do this.

So I can cook up a workaround but I'd like to ask if I'm not missing something obvious here.

Summing up, `compressContext` should take context name as input and output compressed `string` which one can later `Get @ StringToStream @ Uncompress @ string`.

Or whatever that can be used to load context back.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

It seems you want to avoid saving definitions for any System` symbols. Instead of blocking all of the unprotected symbols that could be used, another idea is to modify the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) format of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) and [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet) so that they are suppressed when applied to System` symbols. For example:

```
compressContext[context_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{Set, TagSet, Internal`$ContextMarks = True},
    Unprotect[Set, TagSet];
    Format[HoldPattern@TagSet[s_Symbol, __], InputForm] /; Context[Unevaluated[s]]=="System`":=OutputForm[""];
    Format[HoldPattern@Set[s_Symbol, __], InputForm] /; Context[Unevaluated[s]]=="System`":=OutputForm[""];

    Compress @ ToString[
        Join @@ ToExpression[Names[context<>"*"], InputForm, FullDefinition],
        InputForm
    ]
]
```

For your example:

```
BeginPackage["foo`"];
    bar;
Begin["`Private`"];    
    bar[] := bar[ $Context, $ContextPath];    
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Applying `compressContext` and uncompressing:

```
compressContext["foo`"]

Uncompress @ %
```

> "1:eJxTTMoPCvZhYGBIy89PSEosio5VsLJVgHGCK4tLUnMTVJzz80pSK0p0FNAEAhJLMmJjDAyNFEA\
>   EnAEAuIobbg=="
>
> "foo`bar[] := foo`bar[System`\$Context, System`\$ContextPath]
>
> "

The space where the [`$Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$Context) and [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$ContextPath) definitions used to live has been removed.

**Initial answer**

How about blocking [`$Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$Context) and [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$ContextPath) so that they are protected?

```
Block[{$Context,$ContextPath},
    SetAttributes[{$Context, $ContextPath}, Protected];
    Save["kuba.m","foo`"]
]

FilePrint["kuba.m"]
```

> `` foo`bar[] := foo`bar[$Context, $ContextPath] ``

P.S. I'm not sure what role `compressedContext` is supposed to play here.

Comment: +1 I will have to modify it to filter out everything except of ``MyPackageContextName`*`*`` because if I have e.g. ``Needs["PacletManager`"]`` in my package and e.g. `CreatePaclet` is mentioned inside, it will be stored. And it is quite natural not to expect this ;)

Comment: @Kuba Do you have access to the file where the package lives? If so, you couldn't you just compress that file?

Comment: The point of this question is to go beyond this :) I've already linked a topic where this is done. But see e.g. JLink` implementation, or any other with multiple files and custom loading order. This topic is for them. (ofc I am not interested in packing built in packages but custom)